# Random number security warning

Tags: python, security, python-2.7, python-3.x, random

Why shouldn't we use the `Random` class in Python for security purposes? The documentation asks us to use `os.urandom()` or `SystemRandom` for a cryptically secure pseudo-random number generator.

What happens if I use this class for security purposes?

Comment: If you have to ask, you shouldn't be designing cryptography from scratch to begin with, even using a better RNG. (Even if you don't have to ask, if you don't have several PhDs you probably shouldn't be trying to design crypto from scratch).

Comment: What happens? Happens that an attacker reading just a small amount of data can guess the state of the pseudo-random number generator, which means he can break the cipher you are using. A secure PRNG should be resistant to these kind of attacks: watching the generated sequence shouldn't allow to guess the internal state, even if the attacker is able to read *big* amounts of it.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about cryptology and should be moved to cryptography.SE. There is *nothing* inherent in your question that makes it python-related, except that you read about this advise in the python documentation.

Comment: @Wooble Using a cryptically secure value doesn't necessarily mean that you are designing cryptography from scratch. You may just need an unpredictable random number - e.g. password or token generation. There are many legitimate uses other than cryptography itself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem with Random is that it uses a [Pseudorandom Number Generator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudorandom_number_generator) which is predictable because it uses a seed to generate the random number while `os.urandom()` is using the OS implementation of the random numbers which is more secure

Comment: @thegrinner: Thanks for you answers. I understood that when a random number is generated using a seed, we can reproduce the same sequence of numbers by using the same seed. That's the reason why it's not safe to use PRNG that uses a seed. However, the os does not generate random numbers using a seed. Hence, it's almost impossible to guess the random number.

Comment: @stickypens FYI, the actual answerer is youssefhassan, not myself. I just edited his question to improve some formatting.